# Spring batch FlatFileItemWriter writing model containing a property of List type

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am facing a problem in Spring batch. I have a model like this, and I want to generate a csv file out of this model, containing the field values.

```
 public class A {
       private B b;
       private List<C> c; 

       // getters and setters ...
}
```

B class and C classes can contain other nested objects (typically there are objects generated by JAXB)

The problem that I have is that the FlatFileItemWriter actually writing the references of B and C, instead of the values of B and C fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom [LineAggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/LineAggregator.html) implementation if standard ones don't fits your need